# 3d Portrait tilt effect with translate3d and depth map

Tags: css-animations, translate3d

I'm looking for a way to animate a 2d image on hover to make it appear 3d(ish). Here is a good example: http://www.alexandrerochet.com/about
When you move your cursor the image tilts and appears somewhat 3d(ish). I tried to read the code, but can't find the corresponding script. It is created using a second image providing a depth map.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a tutorial where you learn how to flip a card in 3d.
This is the source: [http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html][1]

The important line:

```
#card.flipped {
  transform: translateX( -100% ) rotateY( -180deg );
}
```

I also created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/902/) which is a copy with the example code.

Hope that helps.